# Splitting a string from API into two parts starting from a bracket

Tags: java, android, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a method that checks if a quote generated from an API is within 130 characters, before split it into two parts, the front part is the quote and second part is the author.

The html output of the API quote is: (for example) "Kindness in words creates confidence. (Lao Tzu)"

I want to show them in two separate textviews and remove the brackets.
Textview 1 - Quote
Textview 2 - Author(removed brackets)

Unfortunately, the app crashed and show IndexOutOfBoundsException sometimes, is there any other method to do this?

Thank you in advanced.

```
private void check(String quote){

        //check length
        int length = quote.length();

        if (length <= 130) {

            //split to quote and author strings
            String[] parts = quote.split(Pattern.quote("(")); // Split on ( into 2 parts, quote and author
            String part1 = parts[0]; //quote
            String part2 = parts[1]; //author with )

            String removedSymbolsPart2 = part2.replaceAll("\\)", ""); //remove ) symbol

            String finalQuote = Html.fromHtml(part1).toString();
            String finalAuthor = Html.fromHtml(removedSymbolsPart2).toString();

            quoteTextViewMain.setText(finalQuote);
            authorTextViewMain.setText(finalAuthor);

        } else {
            //get another quote
            getQuote();
        }
    }
```

Index out of bound error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.amethyst.secretgarden, PID: 21802
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at com.amethyst.secretgarden.MainActivity.check(MainActivity.java:83)
        at com.amethyst.secretgarden.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:24)
        at com.amethyst.secretgarden.MainActivity$4.success(MainActivity.java:106)
        at com.amethyst.secretgarden.MainActivity$4.success(MainActivity.java:103)
        at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$7.invoke(Deserializable.kt:150)
        at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$7.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$asyncRequest$1$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:192)
        at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$asyncRequest$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.RequestExecutionOptionsKt$sam$java_lang_Runnable$0.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:500)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:913)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21802 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you try debuggnig your code?

Comment: @Amongalen do you mean Run-> Debug App? I did it and it still crashed sometimes and shows ArrayIndexoutofboundsexception ..

Comment: Hi, you should check that the quote contains parenthesis before splitting... Also I don't know what are your "Html" classes.

Comment: @user2447161 Hi, about the "Html.html()" I used it to change the html from to string to display it in textview, like this : textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
String [] parts = quote.split ("(");  // no pattern neeeded
if (parts.length > 1) {
     String part1 = parts[0]; //quote
     String part2 = parts[1]; //author with )

     String removedSymbolsPart2 = part2.replace(")", "");  // not replaceAll
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the variable name to match yours and forgot that part.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String tmp = "Kindness in words creates confidence. (Lao Tzu)";

 int index1 = tmp.indexOf("(");
 int index2 = tmp.indexOf(")");

 if(index1 > 0 && index2 > 0){
 String Author = tmp.substring(index1+1,index2);
 String quote  = tmp.substring(0,index1);
 System.out.println(Author);
 System.out.println(quote);
 }
```

Output

```
Lao Tzu
Kindness in words creates confidence.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! I'll try it :)